# Java Array Load from Attribute

Tags: java

I'm trying to override Variables that are already defined.

Here is my code:

```
package com.diesal11;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public class Test{

private class List {
    public String[] words;

    public List(String[] array) {
        this.words = array;
    }
}

public List[] all;

public Test() {
    this.all = new List[2];
    String[] array = new String[2];

    array[0] = "One";
    array[1] = "Two";
    this.all[0] = new List(array);

    array[0] = "Three";
    array[1] = "Four";
    this.all[1] = new List(array);

    System.out.println(this.all[0].words[0]);
    System.out.println(this.all[0].words[1]);
    System.out.println(this.all[1].words[0]);
    System.out.println(this.all[1].words[1]);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test test = new Test();
}
```

}

The problem is the console prints out:

```
Three
Four
Three
Four
```

How can I fix this? the actual code I need this for is setup in this way so it can't change much.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are storing a reference to the array passed to the List constructor.
You then change that same array and pass it to the 2nd List object.

Instead, create a *new* array and pass that in like this:

```
...
String[] array = new String[2];

array[0] = "One";
array[1] = "Two";
this.all[0] = new List(array);

array = new String[2]; // CREATE A NEW ARRAY
array[0] = "Three";
array[1] = "Four";
this.all[1] = new List(array);
...
```

**EDITED - Added style-related feedback**

Your *bigger* problem is this code has lots of style issues:

- Don't call you class `List`: You should avoid using class names from the JDK, *especially* from the Collections framework
- Make your `MyList` class `static`: It doesn't need to access any fields from the containing class `Test` - it's a [DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)
- From a design point of view, your code has highlighted the problem with keeping references to mutable objects - you have no control over what the calling code does to your object (in this case, as array).

A simple change that avoids this problem would be this:

```
static MyList {
    String[] words;

    public MyList(String... words) {
        this.words = words;
    }
}
...
this.all[0] = new List("one", "two");
```

The syntax `String... words` is called a "varargs" parameter - it creates an array on the fly that only the method has a reference to (although arrays can also be passed in, giving you the same problem).
The only safe way is to make a *copy* of the array and store that, or provide a method that allows you to *add* a word (using a List to hold the words for example)

- In general, try to avoid arrays - prefer using Collections

Comment: Thankyou!
But how is the code junk? I am trying to learn the proper formatting and all. but have no idea where to look!

Comment: Sorry where? i can't see any?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in a new array for the second element in `this.all`.

```
String[] array = new String[2];

array[0] = "One";
array[1] = "Two";
this.all[0] = new List(array);

array = new String[2];

array[0] = "Three";
array[1] = "Four";
this.all[1] = new List(array);
```

The variable `array` points to the same memory each time you pass it into the `List` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You should create new String[] for the second instance; by re-using the first `array` you are merely changing the elements in the same array which `all[0]` and `all[1]` both refer to. In other words, `all[0]` and `all[1]` refer to the same location in memory.

```
String[] array = new String[2];
array[0] = "One";
array[1] = "Two";
this.all[0] = new List(array);

String[] array = new String[2];
array[0] = "Three";
array[1] = "Four";
this.all[1] = new List(array);
```

or to save lines of code:

```
this.all[0] = new List(new String[] {"One", "Two"});
this.all[1] = new List(new String[] {"Two", "Three"});
```

Also it is a bad practice to name one of your classes the same as a common data type (`java.util.List`). This will lead to confusion down the line.

Comment: It was for an example, so it doesn't matter, But thanks anyway!